# How dangerous is this Network?

Tags: network, wifi, antivirus, network-access-control

Our school requires everyone to bring their own laptops for homework, etc.

It uses something called 'Genian NAC' to authenticate users.
I can either use Ethernet or Wi-Fi to connect, but both require a couple of programs to be installed

1. V3 (AV)
2. A security program NAC agent: "My PC Keeper"

If not authenticated [Manually approved by teachers], it shows a specific page saying "You are not authenticated" and it shows my IP, MAC address and computer name, plus a number for tech support.

The Wifi uses WPA2-Enterprise-TTLS-PAP, and **EVERYONE SHARES THE PASSCODE**
There are two Wi-Fis, Teacher and Student
Teacher network can be connected using student credentials.
The Ethernet is... well, the usual wall port.

Just how much security-insensitive is the network?

How much can the NAC agent do on my laptop? It doesn't have the Mac version, though (I don't think that will matter a lot but ideas are welcome).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest only installing these programs in a clean Virtual Machine(VM) you only use while on the school network.  Additionally only allow this VM to connect to the network not your host which presumably has personal data on it.

Refer to: https://superuser.com/questions/413050/can-i-pass-internet-connection-on-to-a-virtual-machine-but-forbid-it-on-host

Answer (score 0):

V3 has nothing to do with anything; it's an anti-virus largely used in Korea.

V3 (or any valid A-V) is required by many Korean security software to enable internet access because without an anti-virus or with one not updated your system is considered too vulnerable. So it's a good practice.

The only thing NAC is doing is connecting to the network in a secure manner (large companies also use a NAC called Escort, or other similar solutions).

Now the network works this way: all traffic is routed through a security server. If you do not have the NAC and AV installed, you do not have internet access. Registering via NAC enables your access. The account you do that on is not relevant from an internet connection perspective (but other settings may differ, like access to USB ports).

The server also allows for exceptions to this rule, practically allowing internet for terminals without the NAC software. But that can only be done by someone with access to the security server.

So, additionally to controlling network access, NAC can also disable access to USB ports and other peripherals if configured to do so (including denying network shares). If it does that or not, it depends on the security profile loaded when you register/login in it.

Best option in such a scenario would be for you to request access without the security application (server exception). That way, you get internet access without anything else being affected.

Note that internet traffic can monitored in both cases.